# Problems with ImplictRegion

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, mesh

Through code:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;

RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 - z^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1,
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   ColorData["Rainbow"][f[x, y, z]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

I get:

[image]

but even if the maximum value is properly 1 for x^2+y^2-z^2=1, the minimum value should be -1 for (0, 0, 1), not 0! What am I doing wrong?

In addition, through the code (which I think is more elegant):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;

A = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 - z^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[
 A,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   ColorData["Rainbow"][f[x, y, z]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

I get:

[image]

and here I really do not understand anything! Why this mess?

Somebody, please, could enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: I looked at the `ImplicitRegion` case but I don't understand it.  Hopefully someone else does and answers that soon.  If not I'll look again later.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `RegionPlot*[region]` is not well documented and does not really behave like `RegionPlot*[inequalities]`. Right now, it seems to be an interface to `DiscretizeRegion` and `MeshRegion` styling. I don't know what WRI's intentions are, and whether they plan to implement such things as `Mesh` and other styling options. (I'm assuming that since it's still undocumented, they're working on it. They seem to acknowledge that there is still work to be done on regions, but I don't know how much of a priority plotting is. Manu, you might report it; requests from clients can affect priorities.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is the following code:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;

A = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 - z^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];

SliceDensityPlot3D[
 f[x, y, z],
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[A],
 {x, y, z} \[Element] DiscretizeRegion[A],
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I get:

[image]

which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5):

`BarLegend["Rainbow"]` gives a generic bar over a range of [0, 1].

```
BarLegend["Rainbow"]
```

[image]

It appears that for `RegionPlot3D` you will need to specify the range manually.

*Update:* adjusted to match your target plot from your own solution.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 - z^2;

color = ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}];

RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ColorFunction -> (color @ f[#, #2, #3] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 75, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{color, {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Manu In all honestly I haven't done much with these functions in recent years (since the addition of the legending functions) so I may be behind the times as it were.  I still hope for a better answer, including addressing of the `ImplicitRegion` case.

Comment: @Manu IMO, what should happen is that `PlotLegends -> Automatic` would do exactly what you want, just as it does with `ContourPlot` (and according to the documentation for `BarLegends`, although no examples use `RegionPlot`).

Comment: @Manu I recommend posting your last update as a self-answer.  There are still questions remaining which may in time be answered, so I wouldn't recommend accepting it (or mine for that matter).

Comment: @Manu I updated my answer to at least be similar to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `PlotLegends -> Automatic` pulls the `ColorFunction` settings only for `ColorFunction -> "name"` and not for custom settings.  Here's a way to somewhat automate the construction of the legend, by using `Sow`/`Reap` to get the range of the values of `f[x, y, z]` in the `ColorFunction`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;

Module[{plot, vals, $val},
 {plot, vals} = Reap[
   RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1,
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1},
    Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Sow[f[x, y, z], $val]]], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 75],
   $val];
 Legended[plot, BarLegend[{"Rainbow", MinMax[vals]}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is it just me, or are those moiré fringes?

Comment: The Moiré effect came from the rasterization. Kinda annoying, but I could not get rid of it (easily).  I think it's from the OP's mesh-function lines.